# Can I get iOS notifications for emails routed to folders?

Tags: ios, ms-office, notifications

I have rules in outlook that routes certain emails to folders. These still appear as "unread" in the mail app, but not in the inbox, so I'm not getting notifications. Is there a way to enable notifications for new, unread emails that are not in the inbox folder?

Comment: I don't believe iOS notifications work in any folder other than Inbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a native way to do this in iOS, but there are *many* possibilities for workarounds. Here's one:

1. Set up [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/) and install the helper app on your iDevice.
2. Create a rule in Boxcar telling the helper app to get a push notification every time a message is received at the forwarding address provided. If you need help with this, see [this help article](http://boxcar.io/services/help/4).
3. Create a rule (or whatever they're called in your email service) which automatically forwards folders' new messages to the Boxcar address.

If this fix doesn't suit you, you may want to do a similar thing with [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/).

Comment: Do you know if this is different now? I just checked and I now have an option for "mail folders to push." Is this an iOS 6 feature?

Comment: discontinued since iOS 10 (Feb 2019) https://twitter.com/boxcar/status/1098634110438912000?s=20&t=Cn0NoSxc2VH0DsDvgaUPbQ

Answer (score 1):

I have test in iOS 9.3 but surely this will be available in previous version as well. Below are the steps to achieve this:

1. Go to Mail app. In Mailboxes, you will find "Edit" button in navigation bar.
2. Click "Edit" button and you will find "Add Mailbox" in table list.
3. Click on "Add Mailbox" and select the folder for which you want to receive the notification.
4. Once selected folder, click "Done" and there you G000..... you will start receiving the notifications for those folders as well.

Comment: not available in iOS 13